# Multiple axes in r plotly - plots only last axe

Tags: r, plotly, axes

When i try to plot multiple traces on different axes only the last one is shown.

Firstly let's assume I plot everything one one axe:

```
temp <- data.frame(x = c('a','b','c','d','e'),
 a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
 b = c(10,20,30,40,50),
 c = c(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5))
 p = plot_ly()
 for(l in c('a','b','c')){
     x = temp[,'x']
     y = temp[, l]
     p <- p %>%
         add_trace(x = x, y = y)
    }
```

[What i've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35D0.png)

Problem is that big numbers overwhelm small and you cannot i.e. compare green bars.
So i decided to use diffrent axes like below

```
p = plot_ly()
i=0
for(l in c('a','b','c')){
    i=i+1
    x = temp[,'x']
    y = temp[, l]
    p <- p %>%
        add_trace(x = x, y = y, yaxis = paste('y',i,sep=''))
    }
```

[What i've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQMU3.png)

As you can see there is only trace for last axe plotted. Overlaying is not a problem. On the below image i disabled trace2 and nothing at all is plotted this time.

[Nothing plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xufjx.png)

I know that layout can be an issue and I tried many different ways with setting it up but with no effect.
I am going to use it with app where user pick up fields (also dynamically generated) which will be plotted on chart. So crucial for me is that the solution cannot assume hardcoding any fields names.